# How to test EJB Beans in OpenEJB with JUnit5?

Tags: unit-testing, ejb, junit5, apache-tomee, openejb

In JUnit 4, I use the following setup to test my EJB beans:

```
@RunWith(EJBContainerRunner.class)
public class MyEETestWithOneOpenEJB {
    @Inject
    private ACdiBean bean;
 
    @Test
    public void theTest() {
        // do test
    }
}
```

But in JUnit 5, there is no `@RunWith(...)` anymore.

**Question:** How to test with JUnit 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to write your own EJBContainerExtension to replace the Runner or find an already existing one. The latter is unfortunately not very likely at this moment, JUnit5 is still not in GA and there are not many official extensions yet.

[If you want to, read about JUnit 5 extension model here](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions)

Answer (score 1):

TomEE 8 (since 8.0.7) supports testing with JUnit 5 only (without a transient dependency towards JUnit 4).

### The Legacy Way

The legacy `EJBContainerRunner` was replaced by a related JUnit 5 extension.

If you are using Maven, you would need to add the following dependency to your `pom` file:

```
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.tomee</groupId>
         <artifactId>openejb-junit5-backward</artifactId>
         <version>8.0.9</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
```

Subsequently, you can replace

```
@RunWith(EJBContainerRunner.class)
```

with

```
@RunWithEjbContainer
```

which is a pure JUnit 5 extension. There is no need to add any JUnit 4 dependency into your classpath. A usage example can be found in the [module's test source](https://github.com/apache/tomee/tree/master/container/openejb-junit5-backward/src/test/java/org/apache/openejb/junit5) at the TomEE GitHub repository.

### The Modern Way

In the same release, the `ApplicationComposer` was enhanced to support JUnit 5 as an extension. To use it, add

```
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.tomee</groupId>
         <artifactId>openejb-junit5</artifactId>
         <version>8.0.9</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
```

to your classpath. `ApplicationComposer` does not require classpath scanning and is faster than the alternative mentioned above.

Just add `@RunWithApplicationComposer` to your JUnit 5 test class. By default, the container lifecycle is bound to the lifecycle of the test instance. However, other modes are available as well:

- `PER_EACH`: A container is started for each test method
- `PER_ALL`: A container is started for each test class
- `PER_JVM`: A container is started once per JVM
- `AUTO` (default): A container is started based on the test instance lifecycle.

An example can be found in the examples section of the [TomEE GitHub repository](https://github.com/apache/tomee/tree/master/examples/junit5-application-composer).

Comment: Might there be a c&p issue? I think you mean the artifactId "openejb-junit5" in the modern way chapter, right? As documented in your last link.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I updated the maven snippet